# android "no applications can perform this action" using "send_multiple", sendto works fine

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I need to attach a number of files to an email, but I'm getting an error when calling the intent.

If I use Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, the chooser returns the Gmail app, and the generic email client. However, if I try to pass Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE as the parameter, I get no applications capable of receiving the intent. How do I solve this?

Here's the code I'm using.

```
            ArrayList<Uri> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
            File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "appFolder");
            if (path.exists()){
                for (File child : path.listFiles()) {
                    attachments.add(Uri.fromFile(child));
                }
                //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);//This works, but I can't attach several files.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);//This is the part that SHOULD work, but doesn't...
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachments);
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    anfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting rid of `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));`. `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` does not use `setData()`.

Then, get rid of `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");`. There is no requirement for any `ACTION_SEND_*` to honor both `EXTRA_STREAM` and `EXTRA_TEXT`. Since you are not using the text, you will get more reliable results if you remove that extra. If you do insist on keeping it, you need to use `put...ArrayListExtra()`, not `putExtra()`, as `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is expecting an array, not a single value.

Even after these changes, though, you may still not get any activities. Few apps implement `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, and only a subset of them will support `message/rfc822`.

Comment: It worked just fine! I wasn't expecting that just by removing a pair of optional parameters would work. Thanks.

Comment: @Stalker: The extra is optional. `setData()`, on the other hand, says that you are expecting activities to support that `Uri`. In your case, you would be saying that you are expecting activities to support `mailto:`. Since no `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` implementation is supposed to use the `Uri`, their `<intent-filter>` will not advertise that they support `mailto:`. Net: no matches on your `Intent`. Removing that `Uri` removes that requirement of matches, opening up other candidates. Just remember that you still have to handle devices that have no such matches.